# Showing args of multiple react components in one table

Tags: storybook

I'd like to know whether It's possible to view arguments of multiple components in one table in a story. I'm migrating to storybook 7, in storybook 6.5, did that in two ways:

1. using ComponentsTable in *.stories.mdx like this:

   <ComponentsTable components={{ FileInput, FileRecord }} />

However, this is not working in storybook 7, as I get this error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'docs')
```

2. with component and subcomponents in default export in *.stories.js. So, like this:

   export default { title: 'Form/TableField/Select', component: Select, subcomponents: { SelectComponent, SelectOption }};

But subcomponents are deprecated, and it's not showing any table either. So, I'd like to know, how do you display argtypes for multiple components in a sigle story?

PS: I'm using PropTypes for my components to define them.